# Angularjs update scope variable without re-repeating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation where I have items being assigned to the scope, such as:

```
$scope.items = [{
   name: 'one',
   value: 1
}{
   name: 'two',
   value: 2
}]
```

Then I'm using `ng-repeat` to display this.  I have a service that pulls data every few seconds and updates this scope variable.  The problem is that it re-iterates when you update it.  I've tried to use `angular.forEach` and iterate through what is currently in scope vs what's new and simply update the values at the appropriate keys, but this doesn't seem to actually update the values, that have already been iterated.

I don't want it to re-iterate every time there's an update.  I have some styles that are being applied within a directive that when it re-renders it ignores those style changes (it's overriding them) also there's just no reason to re-render every item, when only one or two may have updated values.   Would anyone know a good solution for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

ng-repeat have now an amazing option called `track by` if you have an unique value in your objects i.e. `id` then you can use it like this

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">{{item.name}}</span>
```

I've tested it heavily since I had to use $$hash manualy before, it works nice and smooth

Comment: That's a good idea, then in my directive I can just update the changed values in dom, which will be fine for this purpose.  Thank you!

Comment: For me ng-repeat improved a lot with `track by`. Now it doesn't cost you a lot of DOM operations when updating a big whole object and if you shift one element or add one then only those elements DOM will be manipulated